# (Angular / AOT) - Angularfire2 'initializeApp()' not loading the correct config properties

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2, angular2-aot, angular-aot

We are developing an Ionic hybrid app that uses Firebase as its backend. For it, we are using the npm package `angularfire2`.

We have two databases, one for development and another one for production, so we want to swap them depending on the state of the app.

For it we created a boolean static constant (`IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT`) that, depending on it's value, will change `FIREBASE_CONFIG`, which is the variable that contains the database configuration data.

This is the important data in our `app.config.ts` file:

```
    export class AppConfig {

        public static readonly IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT = false;

        public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ""
        };

        public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ""
        };

    public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG = AppConfig.IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT ? 
AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION : AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT;
```

...

And this is the call in `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
...
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG),
...
]
```

Knowing this, our problem is that, when we launch the app with the `--prod --release` flags, if we want to build it or just test it in some devices; using, for example, `ionic cordova run browser --prod --release`, Firebase is always configured with the production configuration (`FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION`), as if `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` was set to `true`, though it's not.

Inserting `console.log`s in different files, we realized that, after building the app in production mode, `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` and `FIREBASE_CONFIG` display the correct values. However, the Firebase production database is still configured as if `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` was `true`, though it isn't.

The first traceable log where the config is the wrong one comes from the file `firebase.app.module.js`, a file from the `angularfire2` package, whose `config` variable in the `initializeApp()` method receives the value of `FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` (as if `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` was set to `true`), even if `FIREBASE_CONFIG` points to `FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT`.

If we point `FIREBASE_CONFIG` directly as production or development (without the ternary conditional operator), the issue isn't reproduced, so we think that, for some reason, the `initializeApp()` is used before the `AppConfig` class is 100% built and considers `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` as `true` always.

Also, if we launch the app for testing with `ionic serve` or `ionic run`, the app works properly, launching the Firebase database with the selected configuration. Therefore the issue only happens when building with the `--prod --release` flags.

Does anyone know a way to solve this, or an alternative way to code it?

Thanks!

Comment: I reproduced the issue in a simple way in this sample project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=186-RqxYPPr4qLysQqXRfU_pF_cnjeCog
After running `npm install`, running `ionic cordova run browser` will show "This is component FALSE", while running `ionic cordova run browser --prod --release` will show "This is component TRUE". I think it's something related with the AOT compiler, though the conditional operator seems to be supported: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Versions used: ```ionic info 
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.13.0
    npm               : 3.10.10 
    OS                : Linux 4.4
Misc:
    backend : pro ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have finally solved it.

It was a weird issue, as all we had to do was declaring `IS_PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT` as an `export const` outside of the class, and manipulate it from the inside. `app.config.ts`(shortened):

```
export const isProdEnvironment = true;

export class AppConfig {

    public static readonly IS_LOGGER_ENABLED = !isProdEnvironment;

    public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };

    public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };

    public static readonly FIREBASE_CONFIG = isProdEnvironment ? 
    AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG_PRODUCTION : AppConfig.FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT;

...
```

So, at the end, it looks like it was an issue with the way typescript compiles a `public static readonly boolean` and not a problem of how a ternary conditional operator is interpreted in runtime.

Comment: I think this is a great, very useful, workaround. Nevertheless it doesn't explain the behavior described in the original question. Does anybody have an explanation?